# Is `interruptProcessGroupOf` intended to interrupt the process calling the function as well?

Tags: haskell, interrupt, handle, child-process

I'm trying to interrupt a `System.Process.ProcessHandle` in a clean way, but when I call `interruptProcessGroupOf`, the parent process (the Haskell code calling this function) gets interrupted as well. Is there a proper way to interrupt `ProcessHandles` / child processes?